# Server-side solution for handling asynchronous tasks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deep-learning, data-science, worker

I'm building an application in React that lets users upload pictures to the S3 bucket. After the upload is finished, I want to spin up some workers to process the pictures through a neural network that will analyze the image and tag it based on its content.

I don't want to run this action on the server itself, rather delegate it to a separate set of instances that will handle the processing. What would be the best solution to handle such a problem? It'll need to scale nicely depending on the amount of data to process.

It'd be great if this can be easily integrated using Node.js or Python if possible.

Comment: AWS Lambda might be of use to you here: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Comment: @SimonK I was considering it, but unfortunately, my app has to run on-premise because of some restrictions regarding the input data.